# What does this error mean: No declaration of property 'decisionText' found in the interface

Tags: ios

I am having a label code for "decisionText" inside  dot-m file as follows :

```
@synthesize decisionText ;  //<<<This generates the error
```

inside dot-h file, the code is written as follows:

```
IBOutlet UILabel *decisionText
```

The error i get is : 
No declaration of property 'decisionText found in the interface.

ps: In the interface builder when i click the label, i can find the name "decisionText" under Referencing Outlets mapped with File's Owner

Stuck on this. :(

---

As suggested I removed line @synthsize decisionText and  used :

```
@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UILabel *decisionText ;
```

Now i get the error : 
Expected a property attribute before 'weak'

---

Dot M file :

```
#import "ClickButtonViewController.h"

@implementation ClickButtonViewController;



//@synthesize decisionText ; 
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *decisionText ;

-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender 
{
    decisionText.text = @"Go for it!" ;
}

-(void)dealloc{
    [decisionText release];
    [super dealloc] ; 

}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}




@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the .h file add:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
     //....
     IBOutlet UILabel *decisionText ;
     //...
 }

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *decisionText ;
//...
@end
```

then in the .m file add:

```
@synthesize decisionText ;
```

Comment: I'd suggest when you declare the property that you do _not_ also declare the instance variable inside the braces. You don't need the explicitly declared instance variable and if you make a typo it's only an opportunity to accidentally end up with two instance variables, the explicitly declared one and the one that the compiler synthesized. (I've seen that bug in people's code here in SO more than once.)

Answer (score 1):

You use `@synthesize` statements with [declared properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html). Thus, your code should probably look like:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    // your ivars go here

    // but this is not needed:
    //
    // IBOutlet UILabel *decisionText;
}

// your properties go here

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *decisionText;

@end
```

If you're using ARC, replace `retain` with `weak`.

And in your .m file, you would have:

```
@implementation ViewController

@synthesize decisionText = _decisionText;

// and your implementation goes here
```

Note:

1. While you can explicitly declare your instance variable, if you omit it, the `@synthesize` statement will create one for you. Thus, you don't need to explicitly declare any instance variable. In fact, I might argue that you should *not* explicitly declare your instance variable because if you have a typo, it only presents an opportunity to accidentally end up with two instance variables, the one you explicitly declared and the one the compiler will generate. I've seen that problem here on Stack Overflow more than once. So, in my example, I've omitted the explicit instance variable declaration and I'll let the compiler take care of it for me and it minimizes the chance for error.
2. While not required, it is often advised that `@synthesize` statements specify a different name for your property's instance variable (e.g., in this case, I'm suggesting that the property `decisionText` would have an instance variable of `_decisionText`). This helps discourage the accidentally reference to instance variables when you meant to invoke the property's getter or setter. (In fact, in Xcode 4.4 and later, if you omit the `@synthesize` statement, the compiler will automatically synthesize the instance variable for you with the leading underscore.) Thus, in your code, you would then refer to the property `self.decisionText` or to the instance variable `_decisionText`. It's generally not so critical for `IBOutlet` objects, but as you start to use your own custom properties, this convention becomes useful.

Comment: I get this error now :Expected a property attribute before 'weak'

Comment: Have you put this `@property` statement inside your `@interface`, after the closing brace, `}`, after your instance variables, but before the `@end`?

Comment: Edited the question, added the dot-m file content there.

Comment: As you may now gather, I wasn't trying to suggest replacing the `@synthesize` statement, but rather suggesting you eliminate the ivar and create a property instead. Glad you solved your problem!

Comment: Ya, your answer was helpful too. Thanks. However, the bug is gone, but the application doesnot yet opens. It's a very basic and beginner one. It runs for a second, and then closes automatically. Going to ask this next question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
IBOutlet UILabel *decisionText
```

to

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *decisionText
```

You can only synthesize properties you defined like that with the @property keyword

Comment: I'd go for weak or assign(if not using arc) for IBOutlets that are not the top level objects in the nib file.

Comment: New error on this : Expected a property attribute before 'weak'

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you are using Xcode 4.4 you can use autosynthesis.

In which case you don't need to declare the iVar you can just write:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *decisionText;
```

And you don't need to write the @sythesize line at all.

If you do this - be aware that the generared iVar will have a leading underscore appended by default, although you should just stick to using the property accessor in this case so it makes little difference.

You can see what you can do in the [Objective-C Features Availability Index](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ObjCAvailabilityIndex/_index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You declared only the instance variable which will store the content of your property but you didn't declare the property itself. I think that the easiest way to solve that is to add in your public interface (.h file) or in your private interface (@interface ClassName () ... @end in ClassName.m file) the declaration of the property.

ClassName.h

```
@interface ClassName : ParentClass
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel decisionText; //This is the declaration of the property than you can ctrl-drag to wire it up to your label
@end
```

ClassName.m

```
@implementation ClassName

@synthesize decisionText = _decisionText //the _decisionText stuff is the name of the instance variable that will store the content of your property

... //your methods

@end
```